# Smarty PHP - If statement with variable in double quotes with slash

Tags: php, string, if-statement, concatenation, smarty

I'm writing an if statement in PHP Smarty and I'm having trouble with the syntax.

```
$post['user_name'] = Chris
```

I want it so that if `$post['post_type'] == "hiddenshared"` and the URL URI is equal to `"/$profile['user_name']"` in this case `/chris`, then nothing displays. I'm having difficulty concatenating the `/` to the `$profile['user_name']` variable. How do I add the `/` before the `$profile['user_name']` variable in a way that causes the `$profile['user_name']` to display the string thats contained within it and not the text `$profile['user_name']`? Or should I not be using `REQUEST_URI`?

Here is my code

```
{if $post['post_type'] == "hiddenshared" && ($smarty.server.REQUEST_URI === "/$profile['user_name']")} 

{else}
    <!-- post -->
    {$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI}
    {$profile['user_name']}
{/if}
```

The if statement reads `/$profile['user_name']` as `/$profile['user_name']`, when it should be reading it as `/Chris`. How should I fix this?

Comment: Try `$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI === "/".$profile['user_name']`

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work. It has to be "/chris" and "/".$profile['user_name'] doesn't put the whole thing in quotes unfortunately.

Comment: then try `$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI === '"/'.$profile['user_name'].'"'`, very peasant way :D

Comment: Adding $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI === '"/'.$profile['user_name'].'"' caused an HTTP 500 error, so I tried deleting the first pair of quotes and then it is read by the system to be:  /'.Array['user_name'].', which doesn't work either

Comment: Thanks for your help Mojo, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the brace delimiters inside of double quoted strings

```
$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI === "/{$profile['user_name']}"
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Seems so obvious now. Thanks Scuzzy!